# How to get originate magento version

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to know the magento version at the time of installing. However, I can able to get the current magento version. But i cannot get the origin version of magento.

Is it possible to get it? If yes, please tell me how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from Magento itself, because an update replaces all core files and there is no update history saved in the database either. You'd need external version control and if there is none, you'll never know.

Comment: So you are saying, when we are doing upgrade magento will not save the version history.

Comment: yes. the table `core_resource` contains the current internal version for all modules but there is no history